# Gitlab CI dynamic ssh host

Tags: deployment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic deployment with a gitlab runner.
I already added a runner in my config.toml:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Deploy-Runner"
  url = "https://my-gitlab.server.com/ci"
  token = "my_super_secret_token"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    host  = "$HOSTNAME"
    user = "deployuser"
    identity_file = "/home/deployuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

In my .gitlab-ci.yml I would then write maybe:

```
variables:
  HOSTNAME: preprod.server.com

deploy to preprod:
  stage: deploy
  script: cd to_my_repo && git pull
  environment:
    name: preprod
```

Obviously I added the public key of my deployuser to the preprod.

But what I get is that he can't find the ssh key, which is funny because it is there!

```
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: no key found
```

Did anyone try to achieve the same. Maybe that isn't even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in **identity_file**. You have configured the path to de public key, but you must set your rsa private key file.

You have to set:

> identity_file = "/home/deployuser/.ssh/id_rsa"